# Question closed, even though it was answered and accepted

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668906/use-outerwidth-in-css) and received 5 answers, one of which answered the question perfectly, which I accepted.

Later, It was downvoted and closed.

I don't want it reopened, but I want to know why a moderator would close and reduce my reputation given that the question:

1. gave information about my intention
2. contained script which was researched
3. was understood by other users
4. received answers
5. had an accepted answer

Comment: Question closing has no impact on reputation.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that.

Comment: @waiwai933 Unless it's closed as off-topic or "not a real question" since those carry with them an automatic downvote.

Comment: FWIW I nominated to reopen it and at least one other person has as well.  But it won't have any impact on your reputation, though if you clean the question up a bit (specifically the title is pretty poor), you might get some of those downvotes retracted or you might get some upvotes to counteract them!

Comment: @waiwai933 - you'll get a -2 from the automatic down-vote if it's closed as "off topic" or "not a real question", but otherwise there's no reputation hit.

Comment: @AnnaLear The auto downvotes timeout after a few days in any case, so their impact is temporary.

Comment: @waiwai933 Indeed.  Question closing can actually help your rep in that it protects a bad question from further downvotes.  It's pretty rare to see a question at less than `-4` or so because they tend to get closed pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With three other votes to reopen, I went ahead and reopened the question.

I agree that while it may not have been the most easy question to understand, it certainly was clear enough to be answered *and* you provided a line of (pseudo) code that attempted to achieve what you wanted to do. Not exactly like the "gimme teh codez" demands we usually see.

All in all, seems legit.

Comment: Thank you, I will edit the question to make it more concise. Should i leave the original underneath or remove it completely leaving only the edits?

Comment: @joecoleman Just leave the edits. There will be a link to the revision history once you complete your edit, so anyone will still be able to review the original if needed. (Make sure that your edit doesn't change the question so much that the existing answers become useless, though. :))

Comment: I will make revisions and ensure they are relevant to the answers given! Thank you